# Why when NFC reader send command APDU to get data ATS operation failed and function not supported

Tags: tags, nokia, nfc

ACR122U Get Data
Get UID
< FF CA 00 00 00 
ACR122U APDU Command

> 90 00 
>   UID: 13 29 DF 97

Get ATS
< FF CA 01 00 00

> 6A 81 
>   Function not supported

Comment: What is the type of card that you use? Is it ISO 14443 A?